# QListView does not display model data

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, qlistview

I have a dialog with several widgets, including two list views, say `lv1` and `lv2`.

For each `QListView`, the class for the dialog has a private variable that is a pointer to the associated data model. Say these variables are called `m1` and `m2`:

```
MyListModel* m1;
MyListModel* m2;
```

The class `MyListModel` for these two associated data models inherits from `QAbstractListModel`, and redefines methods `data` and `rowCount`. Stepping in the debugger shows that these methods are called and return the expected values.

The constructor for the dialog includes the following four instructions :

```
m1 = new MyListModel(...);
m2 = new MyListModel(...);
ui->lv1->setModel(m1);
ui->lv2->setModel(m2);
```

Nothing is displayed in the list views when the dialog opens (other widgets are properly filled, though) .

What could be wrong?

I tried setting a `QStringListModel` as a model for one of the list view. Again, the list view displayed no contents.

What could be wrong?

Comment: what do you return in data(), do you properly honor the role?

Comment: The method returns a `QString` unconditionally. Indeed adding a test to control that the role is `Qt::DisplayRole` solved the issue. Thanks ;-)